# Cannot parse Access-Contro-Allow-Headers on recent chrome update

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors

Code:

```
private static final String OUTPUT_HEADERS = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8 \r\n" + "Content-Length: ";
private static final String ALLOW_ORIGIN = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * \r\n";
private static final String ALLOW_ORIGIN_CREDENTIALS = "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true \r\n";
private static final String ALLOW_ORIGIN_METHODS = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT \r\n";
private static final String ALLOW_ORIGIN_HEADER = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers:access-control-allow-origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers";
private static final String OUTPUT_END_OF_HEADERS = "\r\n\r\n";
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
                    if (line.contains("OPTIONS")) {[enter image description here][1]
                        params = 0;
                        var pw = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                        pw.write(OUTPUT_HEADERS + "0" + "\r\n" + ALLOW_ORIGIN + ALLOW_ORIGIN_HEADER
                                + ALLOW_ORIGIN_CREDENTIALS + ALLOW_ORIGIN_METHODS + 
                        OUTPUT_END_OF_HEADERS);
                        pw.close();
                        reader.close();
                        clientSocket.close();
                    }
                    if (line.contains("GET") && line.contains("/electronic")) {
                        //do sth....
                    }
```

Hello, Recently my chrome updated to version 85, CORS problem starts to occur on my program.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://site1/electronic' from orgin
> https://site02' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cannot parse
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header field in preflight
> response.

I dont know if chrome changed anything on checking the CORS or my code has any problems exist long ago but starts to come up ? I tried to change some of the Access-Control-Allow-Headers but still not working. Any advice on fixing this problem? Thank you very much!

[Attached the screen of the headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L5wj.png)

Comment: The https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L5wj.png image shows that the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header has "`X-\`-Header`" in its value. So I guess you have some kind of syntax error in your server-side code which is causing that. The response-header value isn’t allowed to contain a "`\``" backtick character.